How to paint SharePoint components of a news detail obtained by api on a web page external to SharePoint?
How to paint SharePoint components of a news detail obtained by api (divs with "data-sp-*" attributes and webparts) on a web page external to SharePoint.
Example:
<div>
<div data-sp-canvascontrol=\ "\" data-sp-canvasdataversion=\ "1.0\" data-sp-controldata=\
    "&#123;&quot;addedFromPersistedData&quot;&#58;true,&quot;...">
    <div data-sp-webpart=\ "\" data-sp-webpartdataversion=\ "1.5\" data-sp-webpartdata=\
        "&#123;&quot;id&quot;&#58;&quot;...,&quot;containsDynamicDataSource&quot;&#58;false&#125;\">
        <div data-sp-componentid=\ "...\"></div>
        <div data-sp-htmlproperties=\ "\"><img data-sp-prop-name=\ "imageSource\" src=\ "/sites/Test/SiteAssets/SitePages/x.jpeg\" data-sp-cust-siteId=\
                "...\" data-sp-cust-webId=\ "...\" data-sp-cust-listId=\ "...\" data-sp-cust-uniqueId=\ "...\" data-sp-cust-width=\ "2121\" data-sp-cust-height=\
                "1414\" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-sp-canvascontrol=\ "\" data-sp-canvasdataversion=\ "1.0\" data-sp-controldata=\
    "&#123;&quot;controlType&quot;...true&#125;\">
    <div data-sp-rte=\ "\">
        <p class=\ "noSpacingAbove noSpacingBelow\" data-text-type=\ "noSpacing\">Text.</p>
        <p>&#160;</p>
        <div class=\ "imagePlugin\" style=\ "background-color&#58;transparent;position&#58;relative;\" data-alignment=\ "Center\" data-imagenaturalheight=\ "740\" data-imagenaturalwidth=\ "818\" data-imageurl=\
            "/sites/Test/SiteAssets/SitePages/x.jpeg\" data-listid=\ "...\" data-siteid=\ "...\" data-uniqueid=\ "...\" data-webid=\ "...\" data-height=\
            "334.16915930862234\" data-width=\ "369.39239501953125\" data-widthpercentage=\ "46.9927512150155\" data-uploading=\ "0\"></div>
        <p>more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-sp-canvascontrol=\ "\" data-sp-canvasdataversion=\ "1.0\" data-sp-controldata=\
    "&#123;&quot;position&quot;&#58;&#123;&quot;layoutIndex...;true&#125;\">
    <div data-sp-webpart=\ "\" data-sp-webpartdataversion=\ "1.0\" data-sp-webpartdata=\
        "&#123;&quot;id&quot;...minimumLayoutWidth&quot;&#58;2&#125;,&quot;containsDynamicDataSource&quot;&#58;false&#125;\">
        <div data-sp-componentid=\ "...\"></div>
        <div data-sp-htmlproperties=\ "\"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-sp-canvascontrol=\ "\" data-sp-canvasdataversion=\ "1.0\" data-sp-controldata=\
    "&#123;&quot;...;isEmailReady&quot;&#58;false&#125;&#125;\"></div>

